# PHP: How to save in session generated table, and apear everytime when curent user is login?

Tags: php, html, session

This is table, who is generated when user pick some values in select boxes.
How to save in session this generated table, and appear every time when current user is login.

```
<table border="0" class="table table-hover table-striped" name="raspored" id="raspored" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr COLSPAN=2 BGCOLOR="#6D8FFF">
            <th>ИД</th>
            <th>Предмет</th>
            <th>Професор</th>
            <th>Ден</th>
            <th>Час</th>
            <th>Просторија</th>
            <th>Тип</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    foreach ($_POST['predmet'] as $predmet) {
        $_SESSION['predmet'] = $_POST['predmet'];
        $rows = get_info($db, $predmet);
        if (count($rows)){
            foreach ($rows as $row) {       
                $_SESSION['row'] = $rows;
                echo "<tr>" .
                    "<td>" . $row["ID"] . "</td>" .
                    "<td>" . $row["predmet"] . "</td>" .
                    "<td>" . $row["profesor"] . "</td>" .
                    "<td>" . $row["den"] . "</td>" .
                    "<td>" . $row["chas"] . "</td>" .
                    "<td>" . $row["prostorija"] . "</td>" .
                    "<td>" . $row["tip"] . "</td>" .
                    "</tr>";
            }
        }   
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: You wouldn't want to save the whole table, that doesn't really make sense.  You'd **maybe** want to save the data in the table, and then draw the table with your PHP.  (@Fred-ii- - it's fun to see you on the same questions I'm interested in so often!)

Comment: @cale_b this one's all yours ;-) I just thought I'd give them something to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.  The indenting didn't come through quite right, but it should still work.

```
<?php
session_start(); //call this if you haven't already done so - you'll need to call it before any HTML is output to the page though unless you have output buffering turned on such as via http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering
if ($_SESSION['table_stored_in_session']) {
    echo $_SESSION['table_stored_in_session'];
} else {
        ob_start();
    ?>
    <table border="0" class="table table-hover table-striped" name="raspored" id="raspored" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr COLSPAN=2 BGCOLOR="#6D8FFF">
                <th>??</th>
                <th>???????</th>
                <th>????????</th>
                <th>???</th>
                <th>???</th>
                <th>??????????</th>
                <th>???</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        foreach ($_POST['predmet'] as $predmet) {
            $_SESSION['predmet'] = $_POST['predmet'];
            $rows = get_info($db, $predmet);
            if (count($rows)){
                foreach ($rows as $row) {       
                    $_SESSION['row'] = $rows;
                    echo "<tr>" .
                        "<td>" . $row["ID"] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>" . $row["predmet"] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>" . $row["profesor"] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>" . $row["den"] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>" . $row["chas"] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>" . $row["prostorija"] . "</td>" .
                        "<td>" . $row["tip"] . "</td>" .
                        "</tr>";
                }
            }   
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <?php
    $table = ob_get_clean();
    $_SESSION['table_stored_in_session'] = $table;
    echo $table;
}
?>
```

Comment: This make a session table. but when user logout, and login again, table disapear.

Comment: @ValentinGjorgoski - instead of destroying the entire session when they log out, you could just `unset` the $_SESSION variables that store who they are logged in as (such as their user id, etc.), or if that wasn't an option, you could store the table in shared memory instead (see http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) or using some sort of extension like www.php.net/apcu_add - this is assuming the table is the same for each user though unless you stored a different table for each (but be conscious of memory leaks if you do that and didn't ever free up the tables from memory).